# Link not appearing in div class, appearing outside of it

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to re-create a few elements I've seen online and I've been using Element Inspector but can't seem to figure out why this a href element is loading outside of my modalHeader class.

Here's some HTML:

```
<div id="modalContainer">
<div class="fakeModal">

    <div class="modalHeader"> 

        <h2>Fake Modal Heading</h2>
        <a href="#" class="close">x</a>

    </div> <!-- end modalHeader -->

</div> <!-- End fakeModal -->
```

And corresponding CSS (using [Less](http://lesscss.org/))

```
#modalContainer {
width: 700px;
height: 250px;
background: gray;
padding: 1px; }

.fakeModal {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    //border: 3px solid black;
    background: white;
}

.modalHeader {
h2 {
    background: @dullGray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #EEE; //This makes so much of a difference!!!!
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    padding: 9px 15px;
}

a.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a.close:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: gray;
    }
}
```

Can anyone figure out why the x isn't rendering in the horizontal box I've defined in modalHeader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zack; you give `position: absolute;` to your `a` tag so, give `position: relative;` to your parent div `modalHeader` that's work for you .

CSS:

```
.modalHeader {position: relative;}
```

for more read this article http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 2):

You've set the link to be position absolute, not relative to it's parent container.  Remove the position, and change the top and right to margins.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute position always refers to the element above which is positioned relative or absolute. If there isn't one, it refers to the body. Try to change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` or define the modalHeader as `position: relative;`.